# ASP.NET xmlrpc implementation

Tags: asp.net, xml-rpc

I am new in ASP.NET and i need to implement simple xmlrpc request in asp.net.
Client side(in ASP.Net) should send two parameters like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>sample.add</methodName>
<params>
<param><value><i4>5</i4></value></param>
<param><value><i4>7</i4></value></param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

Can anyone guide me to quick start? Little detail explanation would be appreciated.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: So you want a .NET server-to-server method call?  Does the server in your example have an HTTP endpoint already defined (or is that what you're asking)?

Comment: Yeah, I want Server(.Net) to Server(C++ implementation) method call.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [xml-rpc.net](http://xml-rpc.net/) to easily make clients:

### XML-RPC Clients

(modified to be more specific)

It is easy to create client code which makes calls to XML-RPC servers. All you need to do is define an interface representing the XML-RPC end-point and then use the XmlRpcProxyGen class to automatically generate the code for the proxy.

```
[XmlRpcUrl("http://your url")]
public interface ISample : IXmlRpcProxy
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("sample.add")]
    int Add(int a, int b); 
}
```

The proxy instance is generated using static method Create of the XmlRpcProxyGen class:

```
ISample proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<ISample>();
```

The method on the proxy can then be called to make the XML-RPC request to the server:

```
int v = proxy.Add(5, 7);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking fr a simple explanation and yours was the best I found so far.